# How to fetch mathml data from database in php?

Tags: php, jquery, mathml

I want to fetch the mathml data from database in php, so in my database i have the record as
`what is the value of <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mroot><mn>5</mn><mn>4</mn></mroot></math>` so for fetching this data into my page i have used this `<?php echo $row['database_value']; ?>` but upto `what is the value of`  is showing in my page but the mathml part is not showing, I mean to say is what is there in html part i want to display its result too like

[image]
Do any one know how can I do that???

Comment: Okay I am giving it a try please wait

Comment: I got it to work on my browser, should work for you

Comment: No its not working in chrome but yes working in mozilla why???